# Запуск функций одновременно с запуском django

Tags: python, django

У меня есть функции, которые обновляют данные в бд(хранятся в отдельной папке проекта) как сделать так, чтобы при запуске джанго эти функции начинали работать?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: у меня в проекте джанго есть папка в которой хранится файл python, обновляющий записи в бд. как сделать так чтобы этот самый файл запускался вместе с запуском проекта джанго(использую локальный сервер)

Comment: Редактируй свой вопрос. Предоставь больше информации по своей проблеме. Можешь сделать тестовые примеры своей ситуации - так тебе смогут более точно показать решения вопроса...

Comment: есть папка func в ней хранится файл script,py. как сделать так чтобы при вводе в терминал python manage.py runserver файл script запускался тоже, если он не участвует нигде в коде напрямую , а лишь обновляет данные в бд, которые потом отображаются на html

Comment: Повторюсь - редактируй свой вопрос. Не пиши это в комментариях...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если планируешь разовый запуск функций при старте джанго, то можно воспользоваться сигналами, например:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/signals/#class-prepared

Если же планируется, что твои функции должны запускаться периодически по какому-то расписанию, то стоит посмотреть в сторону celery

https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/getting-started/introduction.html